# RegEx Append insted of replace

Tags: c#, regex

I have the follwowing text

```
{1:F01BSUIARP0XXXX7825287830}{2:I942CRAYIGS0XXXXN}
```

the RegEx I used to extract the values

> {1:F01(?<SwiftTerminal>.{7}).*{2:I(?<MessageType>\d{3})(?<xxx2>.{12}).*\r\n

for the SwiftTerminal I want the result to be appended with AAAA (4 charecters), I tried to use Backrefernece \K but no match is found.

please help me to write the RegEx

Answer (score 0):

Remove the `?` at the start of the third capture group

```
{3})(.{12})
```

This is causing the regex to fail.  Without it, the regex will match and you will be able to find the matches and use them/append to them at will.

Comment: sorry the group was not shown earlier , i have edited the regex now.The expression is working but how do i append the extra charecters to the first group<SwiftTerminal>